# user updates using Mongoose mongodb push not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use MongoDB Mongoose MongoDB push to update an entity such that the dcrLocations array gets the dcrlocation entity pushed into it

This is my response from the MongoDB server

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 0
}
```

Heres my model code
import mongoose from "mongoose";

```
//User Schema
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
            firstName: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
            lastName: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
            username: {
                type: String,
            },
            email: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                lowercase: true,
                trim: true,
                unique: true,
                index: true,
            },
            password: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                trim: true,
            },
            hasSubscription: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            },
        dcrLocations: [
                    {
                        dcrLocationId: {
                            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                            ref: 'DCRLocation'
                        }
                    },
                ]
        },
        {
            toJSON: {
                transform(doc, ret) {
                    delete ret.password,
                        delete ret.__v,
                        delete ret.createdAt,
                        delete ret.updatedAt
                }
            }
            ,
            timestamps: true,

        }
    )
;

UserSchema.index({email: 1, phone: 1})

export default mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Heres my controller code

```
 import {User} from "../../path/to/model.js";
import {ObjectID as ObjectId} from "mongodb";

    
    function functionName() {
        return {
            AssDCRLoToUsr: async (req, res) => {
                try {
                    const {dcrLocationId} = req.body;
                    console.log(dcrLocationId)
    
                    const userToUpdate = await User.updateOne(
                        {_id: req.params.id},
                        {
                            $push: {
                                dcrLocations: {
                                    dcrLocationId: new ObjectId(dcrLocationId)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    );
                    console.log(userToUpdate)
                    res.json(userToUpdate)
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error)
                    res.json(false)
                }
            },
    
    
        }
    }
    
    export {functionName};
```

Any advice on how I can make this work? I have been battling with it for some time now

Comment: req.params.id contains a string, _id contains an ObjectId, so no match

Comment: What code changes do you suggest I make in order to fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352786/convert-string-to-objectid-mongodb

Comment: Unfortunately, @Joe, your suggestion did not work
I edited the code in this post and I am using new ObjectId() to convert the string to objectId

Comment: also convert in `{_id: req.params.id}`.  Since req.params.id is a string, that won't match any documents with ObjectId in _id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

`$addToSet` is used to add unique element in array

```js
import {User} from "../../path/to/model.js";
import {ObjectID as ObjectId} from "mongodb";

    
    function functionName() {
        return {
            AssDCRLoToUsr: async (req, res) => {
                try {
                    const {dcrLocationId} = req.body;
                    console.log(dcrLocationId)
    
                    const userToUpdate = await User.updateOne(
                        {_id: req.params.id},
                        {
                            $addToSet: {
                                dcrLocations: {
                                    dcrLocationId: new ObjectId(dcrLocationId)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    );
                    console.log(userToUpdate)
                    res.json(userToUpdate)
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error)
                    res.json(false)
                }
            },
    
    
        }
    }
    
    export {functionName};
```